# Why can't the std::string constructor take just a char?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, type-conversion, char

While using a function template, I was looking at how to convert a `char` into a length 1 string in C++, and I saw that `std::string(1, c)` converted the `char` into a string using the fill constructor, following the logic of "repeat `char` `c` 1 time to form a string." However, there is no constructor overload defined for `std::string` that takes in just a `char` and turns it into a `std::string`.

Why is this, and what was the design decision behind not including this constructor? It feels like a very natural and intuitive idea to be able to convert a `char` into a string directly rather than having to use a fill constructor.

My goal is to be able to use `char`s and `std::string`s uniformly.

Comment: why do you want just another constructor when there is already one that does exactly what you want? Implicit conversions often feel cool at first but the issues will show up on the long run only

Comment: Have you looked at how many constructors `std::string` actually has?  Enough already, this one would be of marginal value at best.

Comment: `std::string foo({'a'});` <- using the ctor taking an initializer list

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I suspect there is a template somewhere where OP wants to treat a char and a string uniformly.

Comment: @ted Oh, neat..

Comment: @spencer If that's the case, he should tell us so.

Comment: MSVC is happy with: `std::string s{ 'a' };`.

Comment: It should be noted that the `std::string` assignment operator will accept a single `char`.  There is not an equivalent constructor.  This confuses me as well.  I could compile `std::string s; s = c;` or `std::string{} + c` but not `std::string(c)`.

Comment: @PaulSanders  I agree, but that would be a reason.

Comment: @RichardCritten and now you want to add one more to make it easier to see which is used? :) Only constructor taking a CharT is `constexpr basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Comment: @DrewDormann Never noticed that, that is a bit weird.

Comment: @RichardCritten good question. Not sure. But is seems to be exactly what the OP needs... they can try it.

Comment: Yes, it is because I am trying to use a template and use char and string interchangeably. I'll edit the original post now.

Comment: `string to_string(char c) { return string(1, c); }`

Comment: If you want the question reopened, show the template.

Comment: It might be to easy to accidentally write `std::string s(10);` and assume you got a string of length 10. Although they broke that with the addition of `{}` and initializer list. `std::string s{10};` is a string of length 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C and C++, `char` serves double-duty. It represents both a character *and* a number. It is considered an integral type, which means that it participates in implicit integer promotion to many other integral types, as well as implicit conversion *from* other integral types.

Because `char` is overloaded, it is impossible at the level of a function's interface to know if a user passed in an actual character (a character literal or a variable of type `char`) or a numeric literal that just so happens to be small enough to fit into a `char`.

As such, when using `char` in an interface, one must be careful of accidental conflicts with what the user is providing.

Sequence container types (types that hold a number of elements in a sequence unrelated to the values of those elements) usually have a constructor that takes a count of `T`s. This is the number of elements to create in the sequence, constructed via value initialization (there is also has a version that takes a `T` which is used to copy-initialize these elements, which is what you used).

But `basic_string` is special; it doesn't have such a constructor. If you tried to do `std::string s(4);`, you would get a compile error.

However, if you make the change you want, `std::string s(4);` would compile and execute. But it would *not* give you a sequence of 4 value-initialized characters. It would give you a string containing a *single character* with a value of 4. This is because the integer literal 4 can be converted to a `char` implicitly.

It's bad enough that `basic_string` is not consistent with the expectations of the common sequence container interface. But to actively make it compile but have radically different behavior would be way worse.

Furthermore, you can use list initialization to get what you want more explicitly:

```
std::string s1{some_char};
std::string s2 = {4}; //converts 4 to `char`
std::string s3 = {other_char};
```

List initialization is how we initialize containers of `T` with a sequence of `T`s.

Comment: You can't anyway, can you?  OP's proposed overload would not conflict with anything.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Good point. I assumed `basic_string` worked like the other sequence containers, but apparently it doesn't have a value initializing sized constructor.

Comment: Well, what would you want?  Four zeroes??

Comment: @PaulSanders: That's what `vector<char>` would give you. And `list<char>`. And `forward_list<char>`. And `deque<char>`.

Comment: Sure, but in all those cases that can be useful.  But a string of four zeroes has no value at all (unless perhaps you're then going to `memcpy` something into it, in which case you can use the existing 'fill' constructor).  Anyway, I think Drew's observation is a good one, q.v.

Answer (score 5):

A constructor that accepts a `char` would accept any integral type via an **implicit conversion**, so that `std::string(48)` would work but (on typical modern systems) give you `"0"`.  You could constrain the constructor:

```
namespace std {
  template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = allocator<CharT>
  > class basic_string {
  public:
    template<class X, class = enable_if_t<is_same_v<X, CharT>>
    basic_string(X);
    // ...
  };
}
```

but that doesn't seem like a simple interface anymore.

Comment: Or, in C++20, use a `requires` clause.